# Font is not embedded

Tags: fonts, tex-core, embedding

I need to create pdf file with all fonts embedded (from tex source).

But, as I understood, the most common fonts are not embedded by default. Therefore I have problems:
? 8 Error Font Times-Bold is not embedded
? 8 Error Font Helvetica is not embedded
? 8 Error Font Symbol is not embedded
? 8 Error Font Helvetica-Bold is not embedded

How to avoid this?
I imagine three ways:

1. Avoid using this fonts. 
   But they are default and used automatically. I have no font options.
2. Create dvi and convert to pdf.
   But I can't really convert my images (saved in pdf format) into ps or eps. I use convert command in linux and they converted incorrectly.
3. Set some option to latex. Logic tells that such an option Has to exist. 
   What is it?

Please, help me to avoid these errors.

Comment: As Herbert remarked, it is not the default for pdftex not to embed fonts. Furthermore, the font names from the error messages you cited don't sound like what TeX would produce. Are you maybe including a PDF file which uses these fonts but does not embed them?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that illustrates your problem, i.e. produces a PDF with non-embededded fonts.

Answer (score 3):

that is the default that all fonts are embedded:

```
voss@shania:~> pdffonts Test.pdf
name                                 type              emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- --- --- --- ---------
EOEABK+SFRM1000                      Type 1            yes yes no       4  0
YPYAQC+NimbusRomNo9L-Medi            Type 1            yes yes no       5  0
RIFXKL+NimbusSanL-Regu               Type 1            yes yes no       6  0
ROKJSN+StandardSymL                  Type 1            yes yes no       7  0
```

Example run with `pdflatex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}
foo 
{\fontfamily{ptm}\fontseries{b}\selectfont Times}, 
\fontfamily{phv}\selectfont Hevetica
\fontencoding{U}\fontfamily{psy}\selectfont ABCDEFGH

\end{document}
```